# static variable vs non static variable

Tags: java

I have defined an object and declared a static variable `i`. In the `get()` method, when I try to print the instance and class variable, both print the same value.

Isn't `this.i` an instance variable? Should it print 0 instead of 50?

```
public class test {
    static int i = 50;
    void get(){
        System.out.println("Value of i = " + this.i);
        System.out.println("Value of static i = " + test.i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new test().get();
    }

}
```

Comment: A `static` variable is declared on class level, not instance. It will always be the same for each instance. It can be referenced as `this.VARIABLE` or `Type.Variable`.

Comment: As an aside, even for test code it's best to follow naming conventions. It would be more obvious what's going on if your class were called `Test` rather than `test`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's only one variable - you haven't declared any instance variables.

Unfortunately, Java lets you access static members as if you were accessing it via a reference of the relevant type. It's a design flaw IMO, and some IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) allow you to flag it as a warning or an error - but it's part of the language. Your code is effectively:

```
System.out.println("Value of i = " + test.i);
System.out.println("Value of static i = " + test.i);
```

If you *do* go via an expression of the relevant type, it doesn't even check the value - for example:

```
test ignored = null;
System.out.println(ignored.i); // Still works! No exception
```

Any side effects are still evaluated though. For example:

```
// This will still call the constructor, even though the result is ignored.
System.out.println(new test().i);
```

Comment: Technically, you cannot access a static member with a reference.  Rather, there's a bit of "syntactic vinegar" in javac that will let you reference a static using the DECLARED TYPE of a reference variable -- the value/actual class of the variable is irrelevant (and I haven't tried but it may be possible for it to be null).

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, the value is irrelevant - but it's via an expression which would be a reference. It's an expression of that type. Will edit, but I think it's reasonably clear already.

Comment: My favorite example of why this design decision is awful is `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, me too - I've used that as an example in many places :)

Answer (score 2):

The field `i` is declared as `static`. You can access `static` fields either with the `YourClass.StaticField` or `instance.StaticField`. So both of

```
this.i
test.i
```

are referring to the same value in the context of an instance method of your `test` class.

It's considered bad practice to access a `static` field with `this.i` or `instance.i`.

Answer (score 0):

static is a class level variable and non static is an instance variable(object level variable) . So here you declare only static variable and call them different way but same meaning.

```
this.i
test.i
```

both treated as class level variable or static variable.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't declare any instance variable in here.only one static variable.if you declare instance variable without assigning value,then if you try to print that instance variable value using "this" key word you can get default value as 0.