# Java variable can't accesed from one class to another

Tags: java

I have this class

```
public class vartotojas {
String elpastas, slaptazodis;
public vartotojas (String elpastas,String slaptazodis)
  {
    this.elpastas = elpastas;
    this.slaptazodis = slaptazodis;
  }
}
```

And I am trying to use variable in this class

```
public class saugykla {
  public static final String SP_name = "vartotojoduomenys";
  SharedPreferences saugykladb;
  public saugykla (Context context){
    saugykladb = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_name, 0);
  }
  public void saugoti (vartotojas user){
    SharedPreferences.Editor SP_editor = saugykladb.edit();
    SP_editor.putString("elpastas", vartotojas.elpastas);
  }
}
```

I get error on the last line `vartotojas.elpastas` what I am doing wrong after I put dot after `vartotojas` I get no option to choose elpastas I am fallowing tutorial on youtube I did exactly the save as youtuber did... I get error : `error: non-static variable elpastas cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: possible duplicate of [static variable vs non static variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035916/static-variable-vs-non-static-variable)

Comment: Is there any reason you did not create a public getter on `vartotojas`: meaning you add `public String getElpastas(){return elpastas}` or make `String elpastas` public static

Comment: You probably meant `user.elpastas` and please give classes CamelCase names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should familiarize yourself with Java Naming Conventions, it'll make your code a lot more readable (for instance, having your class names start with a capital letter).

Second, you're referencing the class name when you should be referencing the *instance* name. In your case, it is `user` passed as an argument to the method, so:

```
public void saugoti (vartotojas user){
    SharedPreferences.Editor SP_editor = saugykladb.edit();
    SP_editor.putString("elpastas", user.elpastas);
}
```

But that won't be enough. `user` can't access `elpastas` variable. You either need to make it non-private (I'm not sure which packages they're in in your code), or the more preferred way, add some getters to your `vartotojas` class.

```
public class vartotojas {

    String elpastas, slaptazodis;

    public vartotojas (String elpastas,String slaptazodis) {
        this.elpastas = elpastas;
        this.slaptazodis = slaptazodis;
    }

    public String getElpstas() {
        return this.elpastas;
    }

    public String getSlaptazodis() {
        return this.slaptazodis;
    }
}
```

And then, you'll need to access the variable through the getter:

```
public void saugoti (vartotojas user){
    SharedPreferences.Editor SP_editor = saugykladb.edit();
    SP_editor.putString("elpastas", user.getElpastas());
}
```

P.S. You should also think if you want to add setter method, or if initialization in the constructor will suffice in your case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Replace class name with instance name:

```
SP_editor.putString("elpastas", vartotojas.elpastas);

                         |
                         V

SP_editor.putString("elpastas", user.elpastas);
```

For you to be able to access class method through class name, the method must be static.

Answer (score 0):

You are close but having small mistake about local variable.

```
public void saugoti (vartotojas user){
    SharedPreferences.Editor SP_editor = saugykladb.edit();
    SP_editor.putString("elpastas", vartotojas.elpastas);
}
```

when you localize the variable `user` for class i.e. `vartotojas user` in method
why are you using like `vartotojas.elpastas` change the line like:

```
SP_editor.putString("elpastas", user.elpastas);
```

**MORE**

How you can access this variable like `class.field` read static [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). This is basically whole new concept and you must know it (if you don't)

Also I would like to recommend to read and follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)